# flutter in vscode how to remove blue line

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

[image][image][image]

I'm using Visual Studio Code
how to remove this blue lines

Comment: You can read the warning when the mouse is on it. And do whatever it says.

Comment: can someone elaborate how can turn it off these lintings warnings for R files?

Answer (score 8):

What you probably want is just to remove only the blue lines and nothing else, then find the file `pubspec.yaml` and remove or comment the line with `flutter_lints`. Save and Make sure to restart the application.

Answer (score 6):

**Comment this line at the start of the page**

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors
```

**Example:**

[image: here]

Comment: This only turns off *some* of the blue wavy lines. A more complete method is: ```// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_interpolation_to_compose_strings, avoid_print```

Answer (score 1):

```
Press command+shift+p (open command pallete)
Then type Disable Error Squiggles.
And click on that Disable Error Squiggles.
```

Comment: Unless those error squiggles are there to notify you of a problem in your code

Comment: not working bro.

Answer (score 1):

## Rename Your file name to the `login_page.dart`.

> This blue line shows the warning to us because of `linter`. There is a rule defined in the package that the file name must be `lower_camel_case`. This is because `linter` defines the bet practices.

Comment: yaa rename but The lines are still the same.

Comment: In that case please provide the warning in questions and update your question.

Comment: please check. qus update

Comment: hover your mouse on the code with a blue underline you will see the warning message. or you can see your all the error and warning in Problems tab. Please provide that error

Comment: Name source files using `lowercase_with_underscores`.dartfile_names

Comment: see bro new image add.

Comment: did you restarted your vscode?

Comment: yes, but still same

Answer (score 1):

remove `flutter_lints: ^1.0.0` , its work for me. don't forget to pub get

Answer (score 0):

Find **analysis_options.yaml** file in your project and comment out this line **include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml** with **#**. Then save.