# How can I remove the blue under lines of the code they are very irritating

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, syntax-error

[image]

The blue underlines are making me lose attention towards my code can anyone help!!!!

Comment: Do you see any information about the source of the underlines when you hover/click the lines/lightbulb?

Comment: I think there some extension which causing this issue i.e. - spell checker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter in vscode how to remove blue line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69476578/flutter-in-vscode-how-to-remove-blue-line)

Comment: do you really have to edit 400+ files for the next commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the blue lines indicate corrections or the proper way in which the code can be optimized.

In your case, the `children` of the widget indicates that it should be constant because you are not using any variables there.

Just use `const` keyword and the blue lines will disappear. However, if you are going to add some variables in your code later, an error will come because of that `const` keyword. Make sure to add `const` only where you are absolutely sure that the widget is going to be immutable.

Another fix can be hovering over the blue lines and ignoring them by commenting them out.